# Contacting protobuf java controller with an empty array in react

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, protocol-buffers

I have a java spring protobuf controller and a a react FE. When the array is non empty, the java controller can be reached. When it is of size 0, I get 400 on the react side. How can this be resolved?
Spring controller:

```
   @CrossOrigin(originPatterns = "*", allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*")
   @PutMapping(value = "", produces = "application/x-protobuf", consumes = "application/x-protobuf")
   public void setMySpecialItems(@RequestBody MySpecialItemsArrayDTO MySpecialItems) {
    }
```

Protos defined in java project:

```
message Coordinate {
    double x = 1;
    double y = 2;
}


message Location {
    Coordinate coordinate = 1;
    int32 row = 2;
    int32 col = 3;
}


message MySpecialItemDTO {
    int32 ID = 1;
    string label = 2;
    Location location = 3;
}
```

React code:

1.Map GUI elements to proto elements

```
export const mapMySpecialItemDicAndOrderByIndexes = (MySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic): MySpecialItemsArrayDTO => {
    const MySpecialItemArrayDTO = new MySpecialItemsArrayDTO();
    if (isEmptyObject(MySpecialItemDic)) {
      MySpecialItemArrayDTO.setMySpecialItemsarrayList([]);
    } else {
      const sortedMySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic = Object.values(MySpecialItemDic).sort((a, b) => a.indexToOrder - b.indexToOrder);
      const MySpecialItemArray: MySpecialItemDTO[] = Object.values(sortedMySpecialItemDic).map(MySpecialItem => {
        return mapMySpecialItem(MySpecialItem);
      });
      MySpecialItemArrayDTO.setMySpecialItemsarrayList(MySpecialItemArray);
    }
    return MySpecialItemArrayDTO;
  };
}
 export const mapMySpecialItemDicAndOrderByIndexes = (MySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic): MySpecialItemsArrayDTO => {
    const MySpecialItemArrayDTO = new MySpecialItemsArrayDTO();
    if (isEmptyObject(MySpecialItemDic)) {
      MySpecialItemArrayDTO.setMySpecialItemsarrayList([]);
    } else {
      const sortedMySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic = Object.values(MySpecialItemDic).sort((a, b) => a.indexToOrder - b.indexToOrder);
      const MySpecialItemArray: MySpecialItemDTO[] = Object.values(sortedMySpecialItemDic).map(MySpecialItem => {
        return mapMySpecialItem(MySpecialItem);
      });
      MySpecialItemArrayDTO.setMySpecialItemsarrayList(MySpecialItemArray);
    }
    return MySpecialItemArrayDTO;
  };
}
```

2.Call the URL:

```
export const setMySpecialItemsServerAction = (newSortedMySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic, prevSortedMySpecialItemDic: MySpecialItemDic, actionType: MWToasterTypes, raiseToaster: (type: MWToasterTypes) => void, actions: MWBoxActions) => {
  const MySpecialItemToServer = mapToServerRequest.mapMySpecialItemDicAndOrderByIndexes(newSortedMySpecialItemDic);
  return FetchUtils.createPutAction(
    'setMySpecialItems',
    'metrologysetup/MW_window/MySpecialItems',
    MySpecialItemToServer,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    setMySpecialItemsServerActionError(prevSortedMySpecialItemDic, actionType, raiseToaster, actions),
  );
```

3.Define local objects in react:

```
export class MySpecialItemDTO extends jspb.Message {
  getId(): number;
  setId(value: number): MySpecialItemDTO;

  getLabel(): string;
  setLabel(value: string): MySpecialItemDTO;

  getLocation(): Location | undefined;
  setLocation(value?: Location ): MySpecialItemDTO;
  hasLocation(): boolean;
  clearLocation(): MySpecialItemDTO;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): MySpecialItemDTO.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: MySpecialItemDTO): MySpecialItemDTO.AsObject;
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: MySpecialItemDTO, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): MySpecialItemDTO;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: MySpecialItemDTO, reader: jspb.BinaryReader): MySpecialItemDTO;
}
```